# Cannot find other Prezi templates beyond 10 defaults

Tags: prezi

A few months ago when you click to create a new prezi there would be a lot of templates that you can choose from. Now when I click new prezi there are only 10 templates to select from and I can't find the old familiar ones.

This is the page that I encounter while trying to create a new prezi

[image: This is the page that I encounter while trying to create a new prezi]

Are the other templates gone or have they been moved to another section?

Comment: I had the same problem this morning, and I opened a ticket with Prezi -- they fixed the problem, so hopefully you're back to normal!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, they have been moved to another section; when I use Prezi, it shows me all the templates in different sections (basically in 2 categories). So I suggest that you look for another section. Or simply open a help ticket with Prezi.